# An "older" movie about a man stealing a dead man's identity

Tags: identify-this-movie, drama, action, crime

All I remember about the movie is that a man in a hotel in Africa (I think) takes the identity of a man that he finds dead next door. The man doesn't realize that people are looking for the man whose identity he stole. In the last scene the man is lying dead in a hotel bed. The camera then zooms out of the room and out of the building...

Comment: And yet again, any additional details that may help identify it? When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're referring to "The Passenger"([IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0073580/)) from 1975 starring Jack Nicholson.

- [Trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i4oZ9xymXHE)
- [End Scene](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ke2CFuLQ6t8)